# How to deploy client in angular2 grails profile

Tags: tomcat, grails, angular, war

how do I deploy the client side of an angular2 grails app. Using grails assemble just works for the server side.
Do I have to deploy it seperatly or can i put it all in one or two war files. 
I am pretty knew to java/groovy deployment an tomcat.

Thanks for any suggestion or hints.
Torsten

Comment: There are several paths to handle deployments. One options is to combine both client & server directories for a simplified WAR build, and there is a guide for that: http://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html